# Using a Firestore Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this problem. In my code depends of choosen project name I want to retrieve a document from another collection. I am use

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('Users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {

      const newValue = change.after.data().currentProject;
      console.log("Project changed to - " + newValue);

      const previousValue = change.before.data().currentProject;
      console.log("from - " + previousValue);


      // ### FROM HERE DOES NOT WORK ###

      const projectId = firestore.collection('Projects')
            .where('name', '==', newValue).get()
            .then(doc => {
                console.log(doc.data().id);
                return doc.data().id;
            });
    });
```

And I get an error

```
ReferenceError: firestore is not defined
    at exports.updateUser.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate (/user_code/index.js:25:14)
```

So maybe I need another dependencies ?
My package.json is

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

What I am missing? Please give a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will  need to use the Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore collections that are outside of the scope that your function was triggered on. Typically this will look something like:

```
admin.firestore().collection('Projects')...
```